# Decode HTML entities in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, html, html-entities

### Sample conversions:

```
 &amp; -> `&`
 &gt;  -> `>`
```

Any small library function that can handle this?

Answer (score 29, accepted):

I have on my utility belt this tiny function always:

```
function htmlDecode(input){
  var e = document.createElement('div');
  e.innerHTML = input;
  return e.childNodes[0].nodeValue;
}

htmlDecode("&amp;"); // "&"
htmlDecode("&gt;"); // ">"
```

It will work for all [HTML Entities](http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/sgml/entities.html).

**Edit:** Since you aren't in a DOM environment, I think you will have to do it by the "hard" way:

```
function htmlDecode (input) {
  return input.replace(/&amp;/g, "&")
              .replace(/&lt;/g, "<")
              .replace(/&gt;/g, ">");
              //...
}
```

If you don't like the chained replacements, you could build an object to store your entities, e.g.:

```
function htmlDecode (input) {
  var entities= {
    "&amp;": "&",
    "&lt;": "<",
    "&gt;": ">"
    //....
  };

  for (var prop in entities) {
    if (entities.hasOwnProperty(prop)) {
      input = input.replace(new RegExp(prop, "g"), entities[prop]);
    }
  }
  return input;
}
```

Comment: please see my comment to bboe

Answer (score 4):

## A robust HTML entity encoder/decoder written in JavaScript.

https://mths.be/he

*he* (for “HTML entities”) is a robust HTML entity encoder/decoder written in JavaScript. It supports [all standardized named character references as per HTML](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/syntax.html#named-character-references), handles [ambiguous ampersands](https://mathiasbynens.be/notes/ambiguous-ampersands) and other edge cases [just like a browser would](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/syntax.html#tokenizing-character-references), has an extensive test suite, and — contrary to many other JavaScript solutions — *he* handles astral Unicode symbols just fine. [An online demo is available.](https://mothereff.in/html-entities)

Comment: the last update to this was in 2018, so I would avoid this library if possible

Answer (score 3):

Looks like this will do:

```
function html_entity_decode(s) {
  var t=document.createElement('textarea');
  t.innerHTML = s;
  var v = t.value;
  t.parentNode.removeChild(t);
  return v;
}
```

[Source](http://www.arkinex.com/javascript/js-functions/26/javascript-function-htmlentities/)

Comment: I have no document object and this should not rely on it, since I'm using JSM XUL.

Comment: You can use the code (http://phpjs.org/functions/htmlentities:425) which relies on a table lookup. You need to reverse the lookup to decode the entities.