# Can hexadecimal html be systematically converted to unicode via Javascript?

Tags: javascript, regex, unicode, hex

I have the following string for example:

"Hi I am testing a weird character Ů, its a U with a circle"

Now my string uses the html code `&#366;` to display the U-circle.  I need this however to be in unicode format, ie. `\u016E`.  Is there any good systematic way to do this with plain vanilla javascript?

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2808368/converting-html-entities-to-unicode-character-in-javascript

Comment: What is "Unicode format"? You mean `U+016E` or its Javascript equivalent, `\u016E`? Or just the encoding the HTML file uses (i.e. the character itself)? By the way, &#366; is not hexadecimal.

Comment: The problem with the answers to the question linked above is that unless you're in a browser, none of them addresses decoding numeric entities.

Comment: @MrLister Yes exactly, the javascript equivalent of \u016E

Answer (score 13, accepted):

If you want to convert numeric HTML character references to Unicode escape sequences, try the following (doesn't work with with code points above 0xFFFF):

```
function convertCharRefs(string) {
    return string
        .replace(/&#(\d+);/g, function(match, num) {
            var hex = parseInt(num).toString(16);
            while (hex.length < 4) hex = '0' + hex;
            return "\\u" + hex;
        })
        .replace(/&#x([A-Za-z0-9]+);/g, function(match, hex) {
            while (hex.length < 4) hex = '0' + hex;
            return "\\u" + hex;
        });
}
```

If you simply want to decode the character references:

```
function decodeCharRefs(string) {
    return string
        .replace(/&#(\d+);/g, function(match, num) {
            return String.fromCodePoint(num);
        })
        .replace(/&#x([A-Za-z0-9]+);/g, function(match, num) {
            return String.fromCodePoint(parseInt(num, 16));
        });
}
```

Both functions use `String.replace` with a function as replacement.

Comment: Shouldn't `[A-Fa-f0-9]` be sufficient?

Comment: @changed Yes, feel free to edit my answer.