# ng-bind-html doesn't work for ng-options

Tags: javascript, angularjs, ng-options, ng-bind-html

I need to sanitize special characters in options, but it doesn't work correctly. Maybe anybody can tell me how i should do it correctly?

For example:

HTML:

```
<div ng-controller="Ctrl">
    <select id="limitType" name="limit" ng-model="selectedLimit" ng-options="limit.text for limit in limits" ng-init="selectedLimit='5'" ng-bind-html="limit.text"></select>
<div>
```

JS:

var app = angular.module('app', ['ngSanitize']);

```
function Ctrl($scope) {
  $scope.limits = [{
    text: 'Afficher &#0153; par page'
  }, {
    text: 'Afficher 10 par page'
  }, {
    text: 'Afficher 15 par page'
  }, {
    text: 'Afficher 20 par page'
  }];   
}
```

Here is link on fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/rfTV2/3/

Comment: you need to add angular-sanitise.js to "External resources". Look [here](http://jsfiddle.net/sja65/)

Comment: If you open attached link then you can see, that i added sanitise via option for angularjs-1.0.3. BTW, when i include include angularjs-1.2 and add angular-sanitise.js in "External resources" it still will not work.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You have three options.

1. You can include unicode characters in your source directly
2. You can [convert the html entities to unicode in the browser using JavaScript](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2808386/39396)
3. Or you can [fall-back to `ng-repeat` and use `ng-bind-html` on your `option` tag](http://jsfiddle.net/sja65/3/).

Answer (score 0):

I think CAT already provided answer. I am just providing readigs for how to use ng-bind-html

1. [ng-bind-html directive](http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng.directive%3angBindHtml)
2. [ng-sanitize module](http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ngSanitize)
3. [$sce service](http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng.%24sce)

Answer (score -2):

Have you tried ?

```
$sce.trustAsHtml()
```

In your example it would be something like this (not tested)

```
function Ctrl($scope, $sce) {
  $scope.limits = [{
    text: $sce.trustAsHtml('Afficher &#0153; par page')
  }, {
    text: 'Afficher 10 par page'
  }, {
    text: 'Afficher 15 par page'
  }, {
    text: 'Afficher 20 par page'
  }];   
}
```

Comment: Could you tell me how should i use it in my example?

Comment: And try to interpolate it as usual without ng-bind-html.