# How can I convert HTML entities to unicode?

Tags: javascript, unicode, babeljs

How I can convert a HTML entity to unicode?

like: `&mdash;` to `\u2014`
or better:

```
const msg = 'i am &mdash lucky' // convert to i am \u2014 lucky
```

or is there any way to tell babel do it on compile time?!!

---

**Edit**

- Don't offer DOM to do this, I need it for both client and server side.
- And I don't want to replace `—` with `&mdash;`, I want `\u2014`.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2808368/decode-html-entities-in-javascript

Comment: @epascarello Thanks, but this is not what I want. I need a library or any function do it for all HTML entities. and not to char, to \u...