# special characters displayed in html when using jQuery html()

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have the following html being returned in my $.ajax call:

```
"<div class="quiz-result-preview">
    <div class="responseText">
    </div>
    <div class="wrong-answered-questions">
        <div class="questionDiv">
            <span class="text-red">1. </span> <h4>Penicillin er ett annet navn for antibiotika</h4>
        </div>
        <div class="questionDiv">
            <span class="text-red">3. </span> <h4>Om jeg er forkj&amp;oslash;let blir jeg raskere frisk av &amp;aring; spise antibiotika.</h4>
        </div>
        <div class="questionDiv">
            <span class="text-red">4. </span> 
            <h4>N&#229;r en person er syk er det best &#229; ta den type antibiotika som dreper flere ulike bakterier, ikke bare en.</h4>
        </div>
        <div class="questionDiv">
            <span class="text-red">5. </span> <h4>Det er farlig &amp;aring; drikke alkohol samtidig som jeg spiser penicillin.</h4>
        </div>
        <div class="questionDiv">
            <span class="text-red">7. </span> <h4>
                Det spiller ikke s&#229; stor rolle hvilket antibiotika jeg f&#229;r, s&#229; lenge det dreper bakterien som gj&#248;r meg syk.</h4>
        </div>
        <div class="questionDiv">
            <span class="text-red">8. </span> <h4>
                Antibiotika hemmer eggl&#248;sningen og reduserer mulighetene for &#229; bli gravid.</h4>
        </div>
        <div class="questionDiv">
            <span class="text-red">10. </span> <h4>
                Un&#248;dvendig bruk av antibiotika p&#229;virker bare samfunnet i form av resistente bakterier - ikke meg som person.
            </h4>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
"
```

As you can see there are some special characters eg. `Un&#248;` , now when i append the above html to my result div , like so:

```
$('#resultTemp').html(data);
```

The special characters display as is, how do i instead display the correct characters ?

Comment: See this, you might have to decode the character before appending: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7885096/how-do-i-decode-a-string-with-escaped-unicode

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Decode HTML entities in JavaScript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2808368/decode-html-entities-in-javascript)

Comment: It appears some of the entities are being double encoded, ie `&amp;aring;` instead of `&aring;` you would need to decode them at least once before inserting, or fix them being double encoded

Answer (score 1):

Use correct encoding.

```
<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
</head>
```

```html
<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
</head>

<div class="quiz-result-preview">
    <div class="responseText">
    </div>
    <div class="wrong-answered-questions">
        <div class="questionDiv">
            <span class="text-red">1. </span> <h4>Penicillin er ett annet navn for antibiotika</h4>
        </div>
        <div class="questionDiv">
            <span class="text-red">3. </span> <h4>Om jeg er forkj&amp;oslash;let blir jeg raskere frisk av &amp;aring; spise antibiotika.</h4>
        </div>
        <div class="questionDiv">
            <span class="text-red">4. </span> 
            <h4>N&#229;r en person er syk er det best &#229; ta den type antibiotika som dreper flere ulike bakterier, ikke bare en.</h4>
        </div>
        <div class="questionDiv">
            <span class="text-red">5. </span> <h4>Det er farlig &amp;aring; drikke alkohol samtidig som jeg spiser penicillin.</h4>
        </div>
        <div class="questionDiv">
            <span class="text-red">7. </span> <h4>
                Det spiller ikke s&#229; stor rolle hvilket antibiotika jeg f&#229;r, s&#229; lenge det dreper bakterien som gj&#248;r meg syk.</h4>
        </div>
        <div class="questionDiv">
            <span class="text-red">8. </span> <h4>
                Antibiotika hemmer eggl&#248;sningen og reduserer mulighetene for &#229; bli gravid.</h4>
        </div>
        <div class="questionDiv">
            <span class="text-red">10. </span> <h4>
                Un&#248;dvendig bruk av antibiotika p&#229;virker bare samfunnet i form av resistente bakterier - ikke meg som person.
            </h4>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```